I have a problem about selection
I don't know why there are two points near the corner(Blue). I want to put it in the middle or normal(Green). How do I do it in the middle?
Thank you

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

It looks like you have stray, loose vertices (not joined to any edges) in your top polygon face. Simply box select them and choose the delete menu with 'x' and then "Dissolve Vertices" to get rid of them.

@R-800 if that were true, where would the actual face dots be?

The face dots should always be centered on their respective faces. Since the dots in question don't appear to be centered on any faces, I took them to be stray vertices and not face dots. Only you know whether they are vertices or face dots. I can't tell from the picture. If they are face dots, mystery solved. If they are vertices, dissolve them.

This is expected behavior. The two face indicator dots are for two different faces (the top and the bottom of the mesh, in this case). They are both showing because you have X-Ray for the 3D Viewport turned on. They are to the side because they are positioned at an average of all the face’s vertices, not their center. There may be a way to change this in Blender Preferences, but I doubt it.
